# browserify and reactify multiple source and destination files

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify

I'm converting my project from `Grunt` to `Gulp`, and have multiple input jsx and output js files. I'm trying to write a [simple] task that'll correctly combine the sources into separate app files. The directory structure is this:

```
├── dist
│   └── js
│       ├── app1.js
│       └── app2.js
└── src
    ├── app1.jsx
    ├── app2.jsx
    └── components
        ├── Button.jsx
        ├── Dashboard.jsx
        ├── Item.jsx
        ├── List.jsx
        └── Widget.jsx
```

Where `app1.jsx` loads some components and `app2.jsx` loads different ones. For example:

#### app1.jsx

```
var Button = require('./components/Button');
var List = require('./components/List');
var Item = require('./components/Item');

// etc
```

#### app2.jsx

```
var Button = require('./components/Button');
var Dashboard = require('./components/Dashboard');
var Widget = require('./components/Widget');
var List = require('./components/List');

// etc ...
```

Different app files will be used in different pages, and components will be shared between requiring apps.

So the idea is to run a task that'll run through the requirements for the different app files and compile the outputs using browserify and reactify to separate files unders `dist/js/`. I got it to work up to the react part using `gulp-react`, but handling the browserification part proved tricky - here's my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var react = require('gulp-react');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var transform = require('vinyl-transform');
var del = require('del');

var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
  var b = browserify();
  return b.bundle();
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  del.bind(null, ['dist']);
});

gulp.task('react', ['clean'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/*.jsx'])
  .pipe(react())
  .pipe(browserified)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

This generates `dist/js/{app1,app2}.js`, but they only contain the JS code that defines the `require(..)` functionality, without the reactified source. If I remove the `.pipe(browserified)` statement, the files contain the correct reactified code, but don't load and requirements.

I would appreciate some pointers on what I'm doing wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your path in:

```
gulp.task('react', ['clean'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/*.jsx']) // here!
  .pipe(react())
  .pipe(browserified)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

You are compiling `app1.jsx` and `app2.jsx` but not the `components/*.jsx` files. You can use [globbing-patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) to fix it:

```
gulp.task('react', ['clean'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*.jsx']) // here!
  .pipe(react())
  .pipe(browserified)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, it doesn't change much - I still get files containing only the require part, but none of the reactified jsx. If I remove the `browserified` pipe, I get reactified files but no no required file is imported to another.